# MariaDB - INNODB skipping the number sequence while creating incremental records - why?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, myisam

I do not know if this is expected behavior with `INNODB`, but I really think it's totally weird.

If I use the same SQL statement using `MYISAM`, the behavior occurs as expected.

**MYISAM**

```
CREATE TABLE main_database.numero (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```
INSERT INTO main_database.numero VALUES(NULL); -- First, run once time ...
INSERT INTO main_database.numero SELECT NULL FROM main_database.numero; -- After, more 12 times = 4096 records
```

**Result (expected behavior):**

[image]

Now if I use exactly the same statement, however, informing that the engine is `INNODB`.

**INNODB**

```
CREATE TABLE main_database.numero (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

```
INSERT INTO main_database.numero VALUES(NULL); -- First, run once time ...
INSERT INTO main_database.numero SELECT NULL FROM main_database.numero; -- After, more 12 times = 4096 records
```

**Result (weird result - Skipping the number sequence):**

[image]

In fact, both engines are creating the expected 4096 records, but I got worried with behavior of `INNO`, because I'm migrating my databases from `MYISAM` to `INNODB` and I do not know how much that can impact my applications.

Comment: Could be an insert that was rolled back?

Comment: This scheme is totally clean/new, nothing is accessing or writing on it. By your question, I do not know for some reason MariaDB itself is performing the rollback.

Comment: This does not make sense. Have you tried to place all 34 INSERTs inside a single transaction ?

Comment: Sorry, but I think that it is not relevant if it makes sense or not, since the statement works perfectly with MYISAM. But yes, I use this statement to create a loop in a single statement.

Comment: Sometimes MySQL trips up. Don't worry about the missing numbers.

Comment: Okay ... of course I can and I will adjust the statement, but I really wanted to be able to understand this behavior or even the reason to respond like this.

Comment: To summarize the reason for this statement, it is a scheduling system that I have that uses this statement to create the calendar table.

Comment: Interesting enough, in that [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57643) that Bill mentioned, there's some workaround by setting the sequence to the max id before inserting new records. F.e. `ALTER TABLE yourtable AUTO_INCREMENT=1;`.  And that avoids the gaps somehow.  A weird bug/feature if you ask me. Probably something to do with a difference in buffering between the engines.

Comment: MyISAM and InnoDB _do_ have differences in this area.  Also Galera, MySQL 8.0, and others add wrinkles to the "burning" (or not) of ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto_increment mechanism is required to generate *unique* values, that are greater than any value it has generated previously. It does not guarantee to generate *consecutive* values.

There's some discussion about it here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57643

There is little importance in generating consecutive values faithfully, because any value could be "lost" for other reasons:

- Your INSERT fails, for example because of violating a constraint like UNIQUE KEY or FOREIGN KEY.
- You roll back the transaction for your INSERT.
- You succeed and commit, but later the row is DELETEd by you or another session.

Auto-inc values are not returned to any kind of queue, because other concurrent sessions might have generated further id values in the meantime. It's not worth InnoDB maintaining a pool of unallocated id values, because that pool could become huge and wasteful.

Also, it might be appropriate to "lose" an ID value, or else someone would think the row they meant to DELETE somehow came back.

Comment: Thanks.... with your explanation, I was able to know what to search for and I found a Percona´s article mentioning this type of behavior and presenting a suggestion of how to workaround -- https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/11/29/avoiding-auto-increment-holes-on-innodb-with-insert-ignore/

Comment: Thanks, Raymond. You are very sure. When I read this article for the first time, I had read very quickly and, in fact, the idea of the article is precisely not to generate a "hole" during the auto-increment using INSERT IGNORE, but even so, it helped to understand the InnoDB, but with the help of the article, I would not start creating crazy stuff.

Comment: @MagnoAlberto - Please provide link to the article; it is wrong in some, perhaps all, situations.  `INSERT IGNORE` allocates the id _before_ discovering whether the `INSERT` will succeed.  Ditto for IODKU.  `REPLACE` simply `DELETEs`, then `INSERTs`, so it will normally always burn an id.

Answer (score 2):

> To summarize the reason for this statement, it is a scheduling system
>   that I have that uses this statement to create the calendar table.

Not totally in the scope of your question which was about missing id's. 
But there are better ways to generate numbers and or calendar tables then repeating a `INSERT ... SELECT` multiple times.
All approaches can be used directly JOINed with a other table or used to fill up a (indexed) (temporary) table

**For number generating.**

If you MariaDB/MySQL version supports windows functions

```
SET SESSION cte_max_recursion_depth = 5000;

WITH RECURSIVE number_generator(number) AS (
  SELECT 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT number + 1 FROM number_generator
  WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND 4096
)
SELECT * FROM number_generator
```

For MariaDB/MySQL which does not support window functions.

```
SELECT 
  number_generator.number
FROM (

SELECT 
 @row := @row + 1 AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row2
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row3
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row4
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT @row := -1 
) init_user_params 
) AS number_generator
WHERE
 number_generator.number BETWEEN 0 AND 4096
ORDER BY 
 number_generator.number ASC
```

**For generating a calendar**

If you MariaDB/MySQL version supports windows functions

```
SET SESSION cte_max_recursion_depth = 5000;

WITH RECURSIVE number_generator(number) AS (
  SELECT 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT number + 1 FROM number_generator
  WHERE number BETWEEN 0 AND 4096
)
SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL number_generator.number DAY FROM number_generator
```

For MariaDB/MySQL which does not support window functions.

```
SELECT 
  CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL number_generator.number DAY
FROM (

SELECT 
 @row := @row + 1 AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row2
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row3
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row4
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT @row := -1 
) init_user_params 
) AS number_generator
WHERE
 number_generator.number BETWEEN 0 AND 4096
ORDER BY 
 number_generator.number ASC
```

The `CURRENT_DATE` is just a example you can also use a fixed date in the past or future as example you can use `'2019-03-01'` .

Also the `+ INTERVAL number_generator.number DAY` can also use a negative to generate a list into the past from that date and other values then `DAY` if you want monthes you can use  `MONTH`, want years you use `YEAR`

Comment: If you are using MariaDB, simply use a "sequence" table, such as `seq_0_to_4096`.

Comment: *"If you are using MariaDB, simply use a "sequence" table, such as seq_0_to_4096."* Can be a option @RickJames But the sequence engine is not enabled by defualt on all MariaDB versions which i think you meant with *"sequence" table, such as seq_0_to_4096*, it is enabled from MariaDB 10.1..