# How to update all values of a column by all values of another column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming that we have table t1 shown below:

```
Name | ID
-----+----
Jill | 850
Eve  | 851
John | 852
```

And table t2 shown below

```
New_ID
------
950
951
952
```

How can we efficiently UPDATE all the IDs in t1 by the corresponding IDs in t2? We can assume that the two tables have equal number of rows. The final result would be something like:

```
Name | ID
-----+----
Jill | 950
Eve  | 951
John | 952
```

Comment: So which part of this is `SQL`?

Comment: The question is SQL. The tables are described in HTML for clarity.

Comment: I've edited the question. The snippets made the request almost unreadable.

Comment: As to the task: What makes you decide for the pairing? E.g. why does Jill get 950 and Eve 951? Why not vice versa? Or giving John 950 and Eve 952 for instance? What is the rule you want applied here?

Comment: As to the problem: What exactly is your question? Are you looking for an algorithm? Or have you tried a SQL statement and the results were not what you wanted? Or what else?

Comment: duplicate of so many questions on StackOverflow that you can just type your question on google, case closed!

Comment: As to MySQL: Which version? MySQL 8 features analytic window functions you may want to use, that are not available in earlier MySQL versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy values from one column to another in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001939/copy-values-from-one-column-to-another-in-the-same-table)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have simplified the example as to make it easier for others to understand. There is no rule that decides the pairing. We assume that we create a temporary table, that only contains new IDs, from a query on a table. This leaves us with a table of new IDs to be updated. We also assume that sorted in an ascending order, we can link the new IDs to the old ones. I am looking for an SQL query. I did try using INSERT INTO SELECT with no luck since I do not have one value to be updated, but several

Comment: @FlashThunder Not really.... I know how to update all column values by one, certain value. Please read my question. This is different.

Answer (score 1):

If a row_number is calculated for both tables, then it can be used to join them.

In MySql 5.7 you could use variables to calculate a row_number.

**Example:**

```
UPDATE t1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 as rn
    FROM (select ID from t1 order by ID) data
    CROSS JOIN (select @rn1 := 0) init
) q1 ON q1.ID = t1.ID
JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 as rn
    FROM (select ID from t2 order by ID) data
    CROSS JOIN (select @rn2 := 0) init
) q2 ON q2.rn = q1.rn
SET t1.ID = q2.ID;
```

In MySql 8 that can be simplified

```
UPDATE t1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM t1
) q1 ON q1.ID = t1.ID
JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM t2
) q2 ON q2.rn = q1.rn
SET t1.ID = q2.ID;
```

Btw, there seems to be a constant difference of 100 between the 2 sample tables, and without any gaps.
So just adding 100 would give the same result for that sample.

```
UPDATE t1 SET ID = ID + 100;
```

Comment: Thanks! The idea seems to be intuitive. Unfortunately, I need to use MySql 5.7. I tried the update query you provided but I get a "Can't repoen table: 't1'" error. We can't always assume that the difference in IDs is always 100. The simple query would have worked fine if that was the case =] Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You can do an update with a `join`:

```
update t1 join
       t2
       on t1.name = t2.name
    set t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Would join work if we do not have equal names in t1 and t2 as is the case given? Also, what are alternative approaches if we did not have the Name column in t2 in the first place as the edit question suggests?

Comment: @user10664643 . . . I don't answer questions that have been modified from their original meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be better if you don't have equal columns.

Create the tables as yours and enumerate as a new table.

```
create TEMPORARY table temp_table1(
Name varchar(10),
ID int
)

insert into temp_table1(Name,ID)
values  ('Jill' , 850),
        ('Eve',851),
        ('John',852);

create TEMPORARY table temp_table2(
ID int)

insert into  temp_table2(ID)
values (950),
        (951),
        (952);

create TEMPORARY new_temp1 IF NOT EXISTS AS (select Name, ID,row_number() over (order by ID) as Numb from temp_table1);
create TEMPORARY new_temp2 IF NOT EXISTS AS (select ID,row_number() over (order by ID) as Numb from temp_table2) ;
```

Then you can update the IDs with the while loop

```
declare n int;
set n = 1;
declare total_count int;
set total_count = (select count(*) from new_temp2 );

while n <= total_count
Do
update new_temp1
set ID = (select ID from new_temp2 where new_temp2.Numb = n) 
where Numb = n;
set n = n + 1
end while;

alter table new_temp1
drop column Numb;

select * from new_temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what worked for me.

As suggested by @LukStorms I created two temporary tables generating row numbers for each one. I then joined the two temporary tables on the created row number column.

I then use the following query to update the values (suggested by Gordon):

```
update t1 join
   t2
   on t1.NUMB = t2.NUMB
set t1.id = t2.id;
```

Note that in MySql there is no implementation of the ROW_NUMBER() function. But it can be emulated by the following example:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT
(@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, firstName, lastName
FROM employees
```

And this works!

Comment: Thx for the mention. A small tip, there is a way without using a row_number. You can use AUTO_INCREMENT in a column definition. But today I noticed this post about a peculiar bug about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55063401/4003419).  But that's only when you do multiple inserts to one using the INNODB engine.

Comment: Another thing, when doing it with variables, an ORDER BY can matter.

Comment: Yes, I do have an autoincrement column. But as the link you attached mentions, this is not reliable. When you delete records from the database the increment might reset to the smallest non used value, causing havoc! Thanks for the order by tip =]